# can't quite reproduce h2o deep features in deeplearning

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning, h2o

This is an attempt to understand what are the deep features in h2o. The function is `h2o.deepfeatures` which is designed for deep neural net.

My understanding is they are just the activation of the hidden cells in each layer. So, by forward-propagating a row of observation, I should be able to reproduce the deep features in the first layer. And forward-propagate again, I get the deep feature in 2nd layer, and so on. But the result is always a little bit off.

There's a few complications but I think I got them under control. First, I normalize my data before feeding it into `deeplearning`, so I set `standardize=FALSE`. Second, I do not use dropout, just to make it simple. Third, I use `tanh`, again just to get a clean nonlinearity.

```
dp <- h2o.deeplearning(
  training_frame = as.h2o(X_train),       
  validation_frame = as.h2o(X_test), 
  x = IV.nm,                    
  y = "y",                        
  standardize=FALSE,
  activation = "Tanh",
  hidden = c(1000, 1000, 750, 250, 5),
  epochs = 1,
  adaptive_rate=TRUE,
  epsilon = 1e-9,       
  loss = "Huber", 
  distribution = "huber",
  nfolds = 0,
  export_weights_and_biases = TRUE,  
  variable_importances = TRUE,       
  shuffle_training_data = TRUE,      
  model_id = "MyModel"   
)

w1 = as.matrix(h2o.weights(dp, 1))
b1 = as.matrix(h2o.biases(dp, 1))
ff1 = as.data.frame(h2o.deepfeatures(dp, as.h2o(X_test), layer=1))

nc = ncol(X_test) # same as Xt.hf
tmp3 = rep(b1, each=nrow(X_test))
B1 = matrix(tmp3, ncol=nrow(X_test))
a1 = as.matrix(w1) %*% t(X_test[,3:nc])
A1 = t(a1 + B1)
A1 = tanh(A1)
```

Now, `A1` is the hand-build activation of the first layer, which should match `ff1`, however they don't quite equal, as seen below,

```
del = A1 - ff1
summary(apply(del, 2, min))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-0.1844 -0.1835 -0.1828 -0.1824 -0.1819  0.0000
summary(apply(del, 2, max))
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.000000 0.001628 0.001692 0.001881 0.001760 0.185080
```

How come?

## An observation

While the min/max of the differences could be off by ~0.18 as shown above, most of the deltas are actually very small. I took random snapshots and found they're very close. So, this might be in the implementation of `tanh` function, or just java floating point vs R?

## New Test

When I use `RectifierWithDropout` as my activation, the deltas are significantly larger.

```
> summary(apply(del, 2, min))
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.3731920 -0.0008961 -0.0001467 -0.0038102 -0.0000472  0.0000000 
> summary(apply(del, 2, max))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.7179  0.7422  0.7472  0.9930  0.7505 40.6782 
> summary(apply(del, 2, mean))
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.005563 0.011769 0.015453 0.046342 0.020242 4.569975
```

This is a bit more puzzling as I would think dropout only affects training. Once the model is built, the deepfeatures should be a straightforward function of the inputs to the layer.

Did I miss anything?